# Table - border not showing

Tags: html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-3

It may look like it in the below image, but there is no border at the bottom of the table. In my code I have it set to the same properties as the rest of the table, but it isnt picking up.  Is it something to do with priority?

[image]

The table was set to 3 columns and 7 rows, I have hidden the first column.

How can I get the border to appear at the bottom? thanks for any replies.

```
<table class="detailstable" style="width:100%; background-color:White; border-left-color:transparent; border-bottom-color:transparent; border-top-color:transparent;">
             <tr>        
                  <th style="width:70%; border-left-color:transparent; border-top-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom-color:transparent; border-right-color:#DBDDFF; background-color:White"></th> 
                  <th style="text-align:left; border-left-color:#DBDDFF; border-top:solid 2px #DBDDFF;">Summary</th>   
                  <th style="text-align:right; border-top:solid 2px #DBDDFF"></th>        
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <th style="width:70%; border-color:transparent; background-color:White; border-right-color:#DBDDFF;"></th>             
                  <td style="text-align:left; width:100px; border-color:#DBDDFF;">Labour</td>
                  <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.FormatMoney(LabourTotal)%></th>
             </tr>
             <tr>    
                  <th style="width:70%; border-color:transparent; background-color:White; border-right-color:#DBDDFF;"></th>          
                  <td style="text-align:left; width:100px; border-top:yes; border-right-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom-style:solid">Plant</td>
                  <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.FormatMoney(PlantTotal)%></th>                   
             </tr>
             <tr>   
                  <th style="width:70%; border-color:transparent; background-color:White; border-right-color:#DBDDFF;"></th>             
                  <th style="text-align:right; width:100px; border-right-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom-color:#DBDDFF;"><%: this.DisplayPlantPercentage%></th>    
                  <td style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.PlantToDisplayWithTwoDecimalPlaces%></td> 
             </tr>
             <tr>     
                  <th style="width:70%; border-color:transparent; background-color:White; border-right-color:#DBDDFF;"></th>         
                  <td style="text-align:left; width:100px; border-right-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom-style:solid;">Miscellaneous</td> 
                  <th style="text-align:right; width:100px; border-top-color:#DBDDFF;" class="FadeOutOnEdit"><%: this.FormatMoney(MiscellaneousItemsTotal) %></th>                 
             </tr>
             <tr>     
                  <th style="width:70%; border-color:transparent; background-color:White; border-right-color:#DBDDFF;"></th>                
                  <th style="text-align:right; width:100px; border-right-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom-style:solid"><%: this.DisplayMiscellaneousPercentage%></th>    
                  <td style="text-align:right; width:100px; border-top-color:#DBDDFF;"><%: this.MiscellaneousToDisplayWithTwoDecimalPlaces%></td> 
             </tr>
             <tr>   
                  <th style="width:70%; background-color:White; border-left-color:transparent; border-right-color:#DBDDFF;"></th>    
                  <th style="text-align:left; width:100px; border-right-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom:solid 2px #DBDDFF">TOTAL</th> 
                  <th style="text-align:right; width:100px; border-top-style:solid; border-top-color:#DBDDFF; border-bottom:solid 2px #DBDDFF"><%: this.FormatMoney(TotalOfAll)%></th>                 
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: do your css class detailstable have border-bottom set to none? Please paste your detailstable style also.

Comment: what is in your "detailstable" class? Please show us the CSS.

Comment: There is a bottom border when the code posted is tested in a browser, so the lack of border is caused by something else: some CSS setting somewhere that overrides the border setting.

Comment: I agree. The HTML code is showing the border at the bottom of the table, so the lack of border is caused by some CSS.

Comment: thanks for the help guys...all correct it was the css referece